# Get path without '~' character

Tags: java, windows, groovy

I have a code snippet that get path of felix home like this:

```
String path = System.getProperty('felix.home')
```

Felix home place at:

```
D:\LongFolderName\Implementations\brannches\MoreLongFolerName\
```

Path will be a string like this:

```
D:\LONG-F~1\IMPLEM~1\branches\MORE~1\
```

I want it must be full path without '~' character like:

```
D:\LongFolderName\Implementations\brannches\MoreLongFolerName\
```

What i have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
// Groovy
String path = new File( System.properties.'felix.home' ).canonicalPath
```

or

```
// Java
String path = new File( System.getProperty('felix.home') ).getCanonicalPath()
```